# The text of a textbox in a dynamic control is not set on post back due to UniqueID change

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, web, webforms

As the title suggests, we are having issues getting the correct text value of a Textbox after a post back.

Context:

- The Textbox is called `textbox_registration`
- The Textbox is in a dynamically loaded control.
- The dynamic control is recreated every post back and has its data set in the OnInit event.
- The dynamic controls are within a PlaceHolder inside an UpdatePanel.

It is expected that the value posted in the form will then be present in the `Text` property of the Textbox. The first form submission is fine, then it gets weird. The UniqueID of `textbox_registration` changes in every subsequent submission, breaking the expected value stored in the `Text` property. The following is an example of the UniqueIDs of the Textbox.

> ctl00$CollapsableSidebar$panel_editAsset$ctl01$textbox_registration
>   ctl00$CollapsableSidebar$panel_editAsset$ctl02$textbox_registration

My theory is that when the dynamic control it loaded in init again it avoids a collision with the previous instance of the Textbox by changing the generated UniqueID, then when the second post back occurs the ID has to be different, and thus corrupting the ViewState initialisation between the init and load methods.

This is very irritating, because looking in the Request.Form collection I can see the correctly posted value.

How can I retrieve the posted value for `textbox_registration.Text`?

**Edit 1**:
Just to clarify textbox_registration is a normal static ASP Textbox within a UserControl that we have loaded dynamically.

**Edit 2**:
To outline the scenario, the source code has been stripped down to the following files:

- [Item Page](http://pastebin.com/5ZztJ9i4), a page to display items.
- [Edit Pane](http://pastebin.com/ZYVse3N5), a custom UserControl on the Item Page that is used to load the dynamic controls.
- [Dynamic Control](http://pastebin.com/WKPLTecT), an example of a dynamic item editing control loaded into the Edit Pane.
- [IEditItemPanel](http://pastebin.com/VkDNzu2R), an interface that the edit controls must implement.

Comment: Could a solution be to convert the `textbox_registration` (which is an asp:Textbox) into a standard `<input type="text" id="textbox_registration" />` and use `Form.Request["textbox_registration"]` to get the value? Or does this prompt security risks, malpractice etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the issue, it was a logical error causing the issue.

Because the edit control was loaded dynamically it was important that the control was loaded for post backs by the end of `OnInit` or up to `OnLoad` as long as the item was loaded in the control before `Controls.Add()` was called.

With this knowledge, the `OnInit` event was investigated closely in the dynamic control. It was being called **twice** on the post backs! A logic error! This caused the controls to be created twice and the posted form values corresponded to the controls created in the first `OnInit` call. Therefore, the second `OnInit` call generated different UniqueIDs for the controls. When the ViewState was restored the controls did not exist.

The solution was to make sure the control is created properly every post back like the first time it is created. The first time didn't make a duplicate control, so neither should the second!

Turns out a look back at the 'Dynamic Controls Basics 101' was needed.
This link '[Dynamic Controls Made Easy in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx)' finally made the solution click into focus.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `ClientIDMode` property when you create your TextBox control

```
textbox_registration.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
```

Then when you want to retrieve the text

```
var textBox = (TextBox)this.Form.FindControl("textbox_registration");
var textBoxText = textBox.Text;
```

Comment: I'm initially sceptical of your response. We've tried what you have provided and the Textbox returned by FindControl is the same one we already have a reference to.

I.E. Object.ReferenceEquals(textBox, textbox_registration) == true.
Therefore we had the same (incorrect) Text value.

Just to clarify textbox_registration is a normal static ASP Textbox within a UserControl that we have loaded dynamically.